# WinUSB driver on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, winusb

I'm trying to use the WinUsb.sys driver that comes with Windows (including Windows 10 IoT of Raspberry Pi 2). Using devcon.exe I can see that the USB I'm trying to use is connected (it is named `USB\VID_1234&PID_ABCD\5&3753427A&0&4`), but I don't know how to force it to use the WinUsb.sys driver.

I found [some instructions on microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283(v=vs.85).aspx) but that seems to be for a standard Windows installation where you have Device Manager available (which I don't have on IoT). The INF file example on this page also refers to a CAT-file, which I assume this is some sort of driver signature, and I don't know how to generate this (or if I even need to). There's also a reference to Windows NT (`Signature = "$Windows NT$"`) and I don't know if that needs to be changed for IoT or not (or if anything else needs to be changed for IoT for that matter).

So, using devcon.exe and some sort of INF file, how can I get Windows IoT to use WinUsb.sys as a driver for the USB device I'm attaching?

Comment: This is better suited for SuperUser. Note that your drivers must be compiled for ARM. Might this be your problem?

Comment: The WinUsb-driver that comes preinstalled with Windows 10 IoT is already compiled for ARM. It's just a matter of telling Windows (through devcon.exe and an INF file) to use this driver for the specific hardware.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I finally got it working. Here's a complete INF-file for future reference:

---

```
; WinUSB installation file for USB device

[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = USBDevice
ClassGUID = {88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}
Provider  = %ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile = WinUSBInstallation.cat
DriverVer=09/04/2012,13.54.20.543

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========
[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTarm

[Standard.NTarm]
%DeviceName% =USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_ABCD

; ========== Class definition ===========
[ClassInstall32]
AddReg = ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,,%ClassName%
HKR,,NoInstallClass,,1
HKR,,IconPath,%REG_MULTI_SZ%,"%systemroot%\system32\setupapi.dll,-20"
HKR,,LowerLogoVersion,,5.2

; =================== Installation ===================
[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include =winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT.Services

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg=Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{ec55ee47-5758-4378-926b-68ed0aec8170}"

; =================== Strings ===================
[Strings]
ManufacturerName="The name of the company producing your device"
ClassName="Universal Serial Bus devices"
DeviceName="The name of your device"
REG_MULTI_SZ = 0x00010000
```

---

Replace the Vendor ID (VID) and Product ID (PID) in [Standard.NTarm] with the corresponding VID and PID of the USB you're adding.
Finally replace the ManufacturerName and DeviceName near the bottom with the correct info for your device.

Put this file somewhere on the Raspberry Pi 2, using either SMB or FTP.

SSH or PowerShell to the Raspberry Pi 2 and go to the folder where you put the INF file.
Run the following command: `devcon dp_add .\<name of your INF file>`

You should see the following result: `Driver package 'oem0.inf' added.`

Finally restart the RP2 (`shutdown -r -t 0` from SSH/PowerShell).

When the RP2 gets back up your device should be listed under "Connected Devices" on the default startup app, and you should now be able to use functionality from `Windows.Devices.Usb` to communicate with the USB device.