# Can't access USB device in Universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, windows-10-universal

I have a USB device that I have [successfully set to use the WinUSB driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317743/winusb-driver-on-windows-10-iot), and it shows up on the Raspberry Pi 2 startup screen as a connected device.

I have added it as a capability to the manifest:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
      <Device Id="vidpid:1234 abcd">
      <Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Now I try to access it from my Universal App [using the following code I found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x1234, 0xabcd);
var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
UsbDevice usbDevice = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
```

The device is found as I can see it when I debug the myDevices variable, but the final line always throws the following exception:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Why? What can I do to remedy this and make it connect without errors?

Comment: What is `myDevices.Count()`?

Comment: `myDevices.Count()` = 1