# WinUSB application on raspberry Pi (win10 IoT)

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, winusb

I want to install and discuss with my own usb device on a raspberry pi with windows iot.
For that, I just create an inf file for arm like [WinUSB driver on Windows 10 IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317743/winusb-driver-on-windows-10-iot). The device is recognized by the raspberry (seen on the startup list of connected device). Then I want to discuss with the device.

First, I have tried with the "winusb.dll" but I need to use the library "SetupApi" that does not compile for ARM. (I used this solution on windows PC and communicate correctly with the device).

Do you have an idea on how to communicate correctly with an winusb device on windows iot?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

So, I try to migrate to Windows.device.usb, and I don't succeed in connecting to the device. There there an exception when I call the FromIdAsync() function. It's exactly the same issue as : [Can't access USB device in Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764102/cant-access-usb-device-in-universal-app)

Answer (score 0):

There are some fantastic samples that can be found here.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess

Download all the samples. Check where it creates watchers based on specific devices (there are two samples in there, you'd need to add your own in) the page that displays USB descriptors checks on the device type -- add in a check so that it returns DeviceType.all to see if it can query the descriptors.

I've managed to get it working on Windows 10 desktop, but have failed to craft an INF file that I can use on my IoT device. Once I get that working, I may return.