# how add INF printer file on RPI3B+ (NTarm) windows iot core

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10, inf

I user **RPI3B+ (OS: Windows iot core 10 v10.0.17661.1001)** and I want to add a USB Kiosk Printer (Brand: SNBC)
I changed the OS in .inf file to use **NTarm** according described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317743/winusb-driver-on-windows-10-iot/33708170#33708170)

and then add .inf file with `devcon add` command, **oem0.inf** generate successfully and name of printer shows in connected devices after restart.
but I don't know how to test Printer to know that is enable and working or it is just a USB empty name

I tried application "CustomUsbDeviceAccess" from "Windows-universal-samples-master" . but it shows not device connected

Here is printer INF file:

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = USB
ClassGUID = {36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}
Provider  = SNBC
CatalogFile =WinUSBInstallation.cat
DriverVer = 05/10/2011,3.2.0.0

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========
[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTarm

[Standard.NTarm]
; POS/KIOSK Printers
%DeviceName% =USB_Install, USB\VID_154F&PID_154F
%DeviceName% =USB_Install, USB\VID_04ce&PID_04ce
%DeviceName% =USB_Install, USB\VID_154F&PID_1001

; ========== Class definition ===========
[ClassInstall32]
AddReg = ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,,%ClassName%
HKR,,NoInstallClass,,1
HKR,,IconPath,%REG_MULTI_SZ%,"%systemroot%\system32\setupapi.dll,-20"
HKR,,LowerLogoVersion,,5.2

; =================== Installation ===================
[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include =winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT.Services

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg=Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{ec55ee47-5758-4378-926b-68ed0aec8170}"

; =================== Strings ===================
[Strings]
Provider="SNBC"
Disk="SNBC Printer Driver"
REG_MULTI_SZ = 0x00010000
ManufacturerName="SNBC"
ClassName="Universal Serial Bus devices"
DeviceName="BT080-R"
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Have you run the command `devcon status *` to show the status of connected devices? This command will show the running drivers.

Comment: This Status Shows:

USB\VID_154F&PID_154F\5&A083CD9&0&3
    Name: BT080-R
    Driver is running.

Comment: But not recognize as a **Printer**

`devcon status =printer`
No Matching Devices found

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the printer USB driver is supported on Windows IoT Core on Raspberry PI. You may contact the supplier of the peripheral to get the sys/inf files.Does this device support serial communication or Bluetooth? I think you can change to use a printer support serial port/Bluetooth instead of USB.

Comment: There is a sys/inf and a .can file in Installation  folder of printer
But I only use inf file and edit it for installing on windows iot
how could I use sys and .cab file for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure the .cab file in the installation folder is for ARM(RPi 3B+ is ARM architecture). On Windows IoT Core, the .inf are processed during .ffu image creation.  Only inbox drivers end up in \windows\system32\drivers, others are in \windows\system32\driverstore.
Just copying a .sys file won’t do the equivalent .inf processing that creates the right registry entries.